# Renaming/copying in windows python

Tags: python

I am trying to copy and rename some PDFs with absolute paths.

ie: `c:\users\andrew\pdf\p.pdf` gets copied to `c:\users\pdf\ORGp.pdf`

Leaving two files in the directory `p.pdf` and `ORGp.pdf`

I've been working on this issue for the past hour and I can't seem to nail it.

Is there a more pythonic way to do it then splitting the string into a list and rejoining them after adding ORG on the last element?

Using python 2.7 on windows 8.

Comment: Will you please put your code? It will help use to understand what are you trying and what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, but I will try to answer it anyway.

This is a python code sample that will copy under the new names, all files under a particular folder, specified at the beginning of the script:

```
import os
import shutil
folder_name = "c:\\users\\andrew\\pdf"
for root_folder, _, file_names in os.walk(folder_name):
    for file_n in file_names:
        new_name = os.path.join(root_folder, "ORG" + file_n)
        old_name = os.path.join(root_folder, file_n)
        print "We will copy at ", new_name, old_name
        shutil.copyfile(old_name, new_name)
```

This code will copy and rename a list of absolute file paths:

```
import os
import shutil
files_to_rename = ["c:\\users\\andrew\\pdf\\p.pdf", "c:\\users\\andrew\\pdf2\\p2.pdf"]

for file_full_path in files_to_rename:
    folder_n, file_n = os.path.split(file_full_path)
    new_name = os.path.join(folder_n, "ORG" + file_n)
    print "We will copy at ", new_name, file_full_path
    shutil.copyfile(file_full_path, new_name)
```

I testing this script on Mac OS, with Python 2.7.7, but I think it should work nicely also on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
import os

.......some logic.....

os.rename(filename, newfilename)
```

Comment: Like your work, Kiran. :) But Andrew wants to retain the original, so `rename()`'s not really suitable here.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the string into a list and rejoining (after removing 'andrew' from the list and prefixing 'ORG' to the last element) *is* quite Pythonic. It's an explicit and obvious way to do it.

You can use the standard `str` and `list` methods to do it. However, there are various dedicated file path manipulation functions in the [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module which you should become familiar with, but the `str` and `list` methods are fine when you are sure that all the file names you're processing are sane. `os.path` also has other useful file-related functions: you can check if a file exists, whether it's a file or a directory, get a file's timestamps, etc.

To actually copy the file once you've generated the new name, use [shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html).copyfile(). You may also wish to check first that the file doesn't already exist using `os.path.exists()`. Unfortunately, some metadata gets lost in this process, eg file owners, as mentioned in the warning in the `shutil` docs.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing to do the rename. I'm not sure how pythonic it is, but it works.

```
 split=fle.split('\\')
    print split
    pdf=split[len(split)-1]
    pdf='ORG%s' % pdf
    print pdf
    del split[len(split)-1]
    split.append(pdf)
    fle1 = '\\'.join(split)
    try:
        shutil.copy(fle, fle1)
    except:
        print('failed copy')
        return''
```